# DAX: Min(Start_date) based on previous date

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, daxstudio

Please lend your hand to resolve my issue facing in DAX logic.

Table

[image]

I need
[image]

I don't know how to proceed with Dax could you please share me your ideas

Edit2:
What if my data is like this
[image]
Batches -B will start on day 1 and complete on next day

Thank you for reading.
BI_seeker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go :

```
Min_Start_Date = CALCULATE(MIN('Table'[Start_Date]),FILTER('Table','Table'[Batches] = EARLIER('Table'[Batches])))

Max_End_Date = CALCULATE(MAX('Table'[End_Date]),FILTER('Table','Table'[Batches] = EARLIER('Table'[Batches])))
```

Hope this solves your query
[image]

Comment: Thank you Sanchit,
I have updated my qusn. Please scroll up

Comment: @prabhu : I am not able to understand the logic behind the Edit2. B3 is on a different date than B1,B2 but the output for B3 is B1's minimum start date(27th). And in second case when B1 and B2 are on different dates (29th& 30th) minimum date is of B2 (29th). On what basis are we calculating Minimum & Maximum date in Edit2.

Comment: Yes, I think I need to verify the source data or I need to add new identifier column
Thank you

Comment: Yes, I agree . If you think that this answer satisfies your query then please accept it as a solution, it will help others who face the same issue.